# Recommended approach to deal with JSON in microservices

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, microservices

I have RESTful API that only deals with underneath SQL Server database. The API method accepts a JSON string. This string is exact representation of EF Entity. Idea is to convert the string to Entity and Save it. Something along the line of code below

```
[HttpPost]
public void ApiMethod([FromBody] string request)
{
    var doc = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<Document>(request);
    _dbContext.Documents.Add(doc);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I wanted to know is okay to expose Entity structure to external clients?

An Alternate approaches would be

Approach 1: Convert json string to dynamic and the build the required entity by mapping properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public void ApiMethod([FromBody] string request)
{
     dynamic anonymousDoc = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject(request);
     var doc = new Document()
     {
        Property1 = anonymousDoc.Property1,
        Property2 = anonymousDoc.Property2
     }
    _dbContext.Documents.Add(doc);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Approach 2: Create strongly type DTO

```
[HttpPost]
public void ApiMethod([FromBody] string request)
{
     var dto = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<DocumentDTO>(request);
     var doc = new Document()
     {
        Property1 = dto.Property1,
        Property2 = dto.Property2
     }
    _dbContext.Documents.Add(doc);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

However I have to create lots of DTOs here with almost same properties.

**Question 1 :** What would be a recommended approach here?

**Question 2 :** (*This question is kind of related to question 1 so I'm posting it here instead of creating new post.)* The API I mentioned above is a part of microservices architecture. I have bunch of microservices that communicate with each other over HTTP. Since all the services are decoupled from each other there is no strongly typed data contract. So I though passing JSON would be a good approach. I am using `Newtonsoft.json` for serialization/de-serialization since it has better performance than microsoft's native DataContractJsonSerializer.
again is this correct approach to communicate between microservices.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @Nkosi - I was able to do a halfway decent job I hope...

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know is okay to expose Entity structure to external
>   clients?

By exposing your entity structure directly across the service boundary you are breaking pretty much every [tenet of SOA](http://architectopia.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/four-tenets-of-soa.html) in some way.

These tenets are there for a reason: to protect you from pain. The pain you could suffer from such an approach includes but is not limited to:

1. Can't modify your data model without breaking consumers
2. Leak datastore implementation-specific concepts into consumers
3. Service layer is basically anonymous and lacks any business definition
4. New consumers have no way of knowing how to consume the service

> Approach 1: Convert json string to dynamic and the build the required
>   entity by mapping properties.

Depending on your exact requirements, there may be a reason you want use this approach. For example, if all you're doing is exposing what is basically a database driver over http, then this approach is probably fine.

However, this does not actually address any of the pain points and so is similar to your original approach.

> Approach 2: Create strongly type DTO

This is a better approach, but only marginally - it addresses pain points one and two above, but does nothing for 3 and 4. I would suggest a tweak to this approach which will address these:

Approach 3: Create strongly type DTO and expose it directly.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoSomethingWithDocument([FromBody] DocumentDTO docDto)
{
    // map from docDto to docEntity
    ...

    _dbContext.Documents.Add(docEntity);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Since all the services are decoupled from each other there is no
>   strongly typed data contract.

Trying to avoid coupling by refusing to share contract does not make sense. A well-defined contract is one of the best ways to decouple services.

> I am using Newtonsoft.json for serialization/de-serialization since it
>   has better performance than Microsoft's native
>   DataContractJsonSerializer

I would be careful if you find yourself radically deviating from a well-trodden path in order to incorporate a specific tool or technology for no other reason than performance. Could be a [premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).